# PostgreSQL: first date cumulative score

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have this sample table:

```
id  date    score
11  1/1/2017 14:32  25.34
4   1/2/2017 12:14  34.34
25  1/2/2017 18:08  37.15
4   3/2/2017 23:42  47.24
4   4/2/2017 23:42  54.12
25  7/3/2017 22:07  65.21
11  9/3/2017 21:02  74.6
25  10/3/2017 5:15  11.3
4   10/3/2017 7:11  22.45
```

My aim is to calculates the first(!) date (YYYY-MM-DD) on which an id's cumulative score has reached 100 (>=). For that, I've written the following code:

```
SELECT date(date),id, score,
sum(score) over (partition by id order by date(date) rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_score
FROM test_q1
GROUP BY id, date, score
Order by id, date
```

It returns:

```
date    id  score   cumulative_score
1/1/2017    11  25.34   25.34
9/3/2017    11  74.6    99.94
1/2/2017    4   34.34   34.34
3/2/2017    4   47.24   81.58
4/2/2017    4   54.12   135.7
10/3/2017   4   22.45   158.15
1/2/2017    25  37.15   37.15
7/3/2017    25  65.21   102.36
10/3/2017   25  11.3    113.66
```

I tried to add either WHERE cumulative_score >= 100 or HAVING cumulative score >= 100, but it returns_

ERROR:  column "cumulative_score" does not exist
LINE 4: WHERE cumulative_score >= 100
              ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 206

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

What I expect is:

```
date    id  score   cumulative_score
4/2/2017    4   54.12   135.7
7/3/2017    25  65.21   102.36
```

And the output just id and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cumulative_sum AS (
    SELECT id,date,sum(score) over( partition by id order by date) as sum from test_q1
),
above_100_score_rank AS (
    SELECT *, rank() over (partition by id order by sum) AS rank 
       FROM cumulative_sum where sum > 100 
)
SELECT * FROM above_100_score_rank WHERE rank= 1;
```